# How to override -DNDEBUG compile flag when building a Cython module

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a Cython module that calls a C++ function via `cdef extern`.  The C++ function has `assert()` statements, and I would like to check those assertions.  However, when I create the module by calling `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, GCC is always invoked with `-DNDEBUG`.  Whenever the code is run, the assertions are not checked.

I can't find a way to override `-DNDEBUG` using `setup.py`.  Is this possible?

Currently the only way I have found to deal with this is to manually call Cython, GCC, and `g++` with the options that are used by `python setup.py`, but to take out `-DNDEBUG`. But there must be a simpler way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541565/how-can-i-assert-from-python-c-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually undefine `NDEBUG`, if it is defined, prior to including `<cassert>`. Add the following lines to the top of the cpp file which contains these assert statements. Make sure these are the very first statements in that file.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
# define NDEBUG_DISABLED
# undef NDEBUG
#endif
#include <cassert>

#ifdef NDEBUG_DISABLED
# define NDEBUG        // re-enable NDEBUG if it was originally enabled
#endif

// rest of the file
```

This will ensure that `NDEBUG` is not defined when the processor includes `<cassert>`, which will result in the assertion checks being compiled into your code.

Answer (score 12):

You can undefine NDEBUG in your *setup.py* file. Just use the undef_macros option when defining your extension:

```
extensions = [ Extension ( "myprog", [ mysrc.c ], undef_macros = [ "NDEBUG" ] ) ]
```

In the build output you'll see -DNDEBUG followed by -UNDEBUG, which overrides it. For more information on Extension options, see the [distutils documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils).

Note, however, that an assert triggered in an extension module will cause the Python, or [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), interpreter to exit.

Comment: setting CFLAGS="-UNDEBUG" is also an alternative to editing setup.py

Comment: Is there a convention for undefining NDEBUG just for test/non-release builds?